# Postman extracting multiple xml values to json as global variables

Tags: json, xml, postman

If i have an xml document that looks like the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<res>
<key>foo</key>
</res>
```

I can extract the variable foo, in postman through the following line easily.

```
var json = xml2Json(responseBody);
postman.setGlobalVariable("key", json.res.key);
```

My question is, how can i save the variables if my xml document has more than one dataset

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<res>
<key>foo</key>
</res>
<res>
<key>bar</key>
</res>
<res>
<key>foo</key>
</res>
```